# Release Management 2013 - getting Deployment Agent 2013 Error when deploying to a server with Enterprise Library 5.0 Installed

Tags: ms-release-management

I am getting the following error when carrying out a release against a server with Enterprise Library 5.0 already installed and used by ESB 2.1 (cannot just uncomment out references in machine.config):

```
16/01/2015 13:58:54 - Error - (1120, 1116) - [A]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common\5.0.414.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'.: \r\n\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.DataErrorPropertyChangedBase.Validate()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.DataErrorPropertyChangedBase.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName, Boolean setDirty, Boolean validate)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.SystemSettings..ctor(Rtm13Services rtm13Services)
```

The Deployment Agent 2013 software installs to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'.

I managed to get deployments working by removing references to Enterprise Library 5.0 in the machine.config file but understand these are needed by the ESB 2.1 software utilised by our BizTalk developers - I understand commenting out in machine.config is not an option.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?